# Automate multiple installers

Tags: python, automation, installation

I have written a small python script that i want to share with other users.(i want to keep it as a script rather than and exe so that users can edit the codes if they need to)

my script has several external libraries for python which doesn't come with basic python.

But the other users doesn't have python and the required libraries  installed in their PCs .

So,For convenient, I am wondering if there's any way to automate the installation process for installing python and the external libraries they need.

To make things more clear, what i meant is to combine all the installers into 1 single big installer.

For you information, all the installers are window x86 MSI installers and there are about 5 or 6 of them.

Is this possible?Could there be any drawbacks of doing this?

EDIT:
All the users are using windows XP  pro 32 bit 
python 2.7

Comment: What OS are you making the installer for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using NSIS. You can bundle all the MSI installers (including python) into one executable, and install them in "silent mode" in whatever order you want. NSIS also has a great script generator you can download.

Also, you might be interested in activepython. It comes with pip and automatically adds everything to your path so you can just pip install most of your dependencies from a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

> > what i meant is to combine all the installers into 1 single big installer.

I am not sure, if you mean to make one msi out of several. If you have built the msis, this is possible to work out, but in most situations there were reasons for the separation.

But for now I assume as the others, that you want a setup which combines all msi setups into one, e.g. with a packing/selfextracting part, but probably with some own logic.

This is a very common setup pattern, some call it "bootstrapper". Unfortunately the maturity of most tools for bootstrapping is by far not comparable to the msi creation tools so most companies I know, write kind of an own bootstrapper with the dialogs and the control logic they want. This can be a very expensive job.

If you have not high requirements, it may sound a simple job. Just starting a number of processes after each other. But what about a seamless process bar, what about uninstallation (single or bundled), what about repair, modify, what about, if one of them fails or needs a reboot also concerning repair/uninstall/modify/update. And so on.

As mentioned, one of the first issues of bundling several setups into one is about caring how many and which uninstall entries shall the user see, and if it is ok that your bootstrapper does not create an own, combining one.
If this is not an issue for you, then you have chances to find an easy solution.

I know at least three tools for bootstrappers, some call it suites or bundles. I can only mention them here:

WiX has at least something called "Burn". Google for WiX Burn and you will find it. I haven't used it yet, so I can't tell about.

InstallShield Premier, which is not really what most people call a cheap product, allows setup "Suites" which is the same. I don't want to comment the quality here.

In the Windows SDK there is (has been?) a kind of template of a setup.exe to show how to start installation of msi out of a program. I have never looked into that example really to tell more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting all the files into a .sfx.exe archive and get them to run it. Extract all files to %temp% and run a batch script to install python.msi and copy the libraries from %temp% to the python library directory. If you want to install python 2.7.5, grab an "Ninite" installer from http://ninite.com/